# Whirling a stone parallel to the surface of the earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, acceleration

Whenever I whirl a stone in a horizontal circle I find that while revolving the string and the stone align in a horizontal plane. But at the same time gravitational force is acting on it which must cause it to accelerate downward . Also the only other force acting on it (which I can account for) is the tension due to string which is acting along the string )which is parallel to the surface) and hence perpendicular to the gravitational force. Therefore string force cannot balance the gravitational force and hence cause it to accelerate downward. Which isn't the case here. So we must conclude that a vertical force is acting on the stone.

But my problem is that I can't account for such vertical force in this case. So what force is balancing the gravitational force here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look more closely at the string.  It is not parallel to the surface.   The stone is lower than the center of rotation.  The tension force is not parallel to the surface.  The vertical component of the tension force balances the force of gravity on the stone.

Comment: You probably mean: The *vertical* component of the tension force balances the force of gravity on the stone

Comment: @ThomasFritsch  #sigh#   Thank you.   Corrected.

Comment: This is similar to the classic experiment of putting a weight on the middle of a string, and then trying to pull the ends of the string to make the string parallel to the ground. No matter how hard you pull, it's simply not possible, as there will always be a vertical component to the string tension which is required to balance the force of gravity on the weight.